# Change content of file

Tags: c, file-io, while-loop

Can someone please break down this code for me? I know it changes text from a user file and I know it could be very useful to me. What is the purpose of "~"? How could I amend this code to read a user file word by word and then change it using the same kind of formula?

```
// first value in the file is the key
if ( fread(&key, sizeof(char), 1, infile) )
{ 
    key = ~key;  
}
while( fread(&fval ,sizeof(short), 1, infile) )
{
      fputc( (fval / 2) - key, outfile );  
}
```

Comment: `key = ~key` sets `key` to the bitwise-inverse of `key`.

Comment: bitwise-inverse...means nothing to me I'll get the dictionary out!

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting here. What have you tried?

Comment: I don't understand how this code works. Basically, I want to read a text file, alter it like the code does above, and put it to a new file. I don't understand however how the code above does it though

Comment: Absent a pretty much complete rewrite, this won't help with the goal you state. There is nothing in here to read 'words' (which I take as English language words, not in the CS sense).

Comment: This is only a snippet of code that changes the characters of a file. I already have the code for taking the characters from a file, I just wonder if there is an alternative to this for the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key = ~key` swaps all the bits of key

You know about bits?

ascii `A` (65) is 100 0001 in binary, so '~' of this is simply swaps each `1` for `0` and each `0` for `1` giving 011 1110 (62) which is `>`

So this will replace all the `A`s in your document with `>` and similarly for every other character.  The nice thing about ~ is that it's exactly the same process to decrypt - just swap each bit back.

ps. It's not exactly mil-spec encryption!

Comment: Well what if I wanted to just add 5 to A? none of this swapping bits? Just simply read A, add 5 to it, and output to a new file? And repeat that process for every character in the file?

Comment: Then simply do key+=5, characters are just numbers in a computer

Answer (score 1):

Comments inline!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* Integer value of 'A' is 65 and 
       binary value is 01000001 */
    char a='A';      
    printf("a=%d\n", a);

    /* ~a is binary inverse of a so 
       ~01000001 = 10111110 */
    a=~a;
    printf("a=%d\n", a);

    /* easier example */
    /* ~0 = 11111111 times # of bytes needed
       to store int (whose value is nothing 
       but negative one) */

    int i=0;
    printf("i=%d\n", i);

    i=~i;
    printf("i=%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}

$ ./a.out
a=65
a=-66
i=0
i=-1
$
```

With the above mentioned hint, could you please try and read the code and share your comments.

OTOH, what is `crypt`? what is its type? what is the value stored in it?!

For more bitwise operations, please refer [this](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/) page!

Comment: I understand now, that ~ replaces all 1's with 0's and all 0's with 1's in binary correct? Sorry crypt is meant to be key!